# Make RefreshIndicator work on whole screen (ListView)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

While looking for solutions, I found some related discussions, but none of the solutions worked in my case.

I made a "RefreshableScrollFrame" widget in my app, which offers a generic frame for pages that should show a StatusBar (loading indicator, etc.) and which should provide a pull-down to refresh.

RefreshableScrollFrame

```
return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 4,
            child: const MyStatusbarWidget(),
          ),
          RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: onRefresh,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              child: child,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Child Option - ListView:

```
ListView.builder(
            itemCount: items.length,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) => Card(
              child: ListTile(
                 title: Text(items[i].name),
              ),
            ),
          );
```

Child Option - Column with the `ListView` and static items:

```
Column(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
                itemCount: items.length,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) => Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(items[i].name),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ...someStaticWidgets,
          ],
        );
```

So far so good, everything works fine, except for one important detail.
The RefreshIndicator is only triggered in areas, which are covered by the child widget. If the content is small and covers just the top of the page, the gesture is detected only in that area.
If the content is just an empty ListView, I won't even be able to trigger a refresh.

I tried several suggested solutions in order to "expand" the child to the whole screen, but I always ran into exceptions, when trying to get rid of shrinkWrap, when adding Expanded(), and so on.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: why you can't wrap the whol scaffold with it ?

Comment: I tried, but that didn't change anything. The refresh-gesture still only worked on the scrollable portion of the child.

Comment: I can follow with it, try do it again and set in the scaffold extenddBody: true

Comment: Oh, that might work. However, i already found a solution that works for me (see my answer).
I prefer if the RefreshIndicators animation starts at the scrollable (content) portion, and not at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work for me, using a LayoutBuilder + ConstrainedBox to wrap the contents of the SingleChildScrollView.
This way, the SingleChildScrollView will always span the whole remaining space.

```
return Column(
  children: [
    const SizedBox(
      height: 4,
      child: MyStatusbarWidget(),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        return RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: onRefresh,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
                child: child,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap the whole body of your scaffold with refreshIndicator not a portion of it.

Comment: This didn't change anything. The refresh-gesture still only works on the scrollable portion of the child.